# How to check Ui-grid cell change event

Tags: angular

I am currently working on `angularjs` application .
In My application using ui-gird.I need ui-grid cell event .

How can we perform ui-grid cell change event ?

ui-grid cell change event means when i am trying to enter any character into the cell then automatically server server side event calls.I am not pressing any tab on enter key just only enter character it calls server side events.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The main upshot of this is that in some instances you'll need to explicitly tell ui-grid that your data has changed. This includes:

when you have updated the content of your data. The grid automatically calls notifyDataChange when data is edited in place, for other changes to the data you need to call notifyDataChange manually. And for handling server call you need to focus on Key event code. So while pressing a particular key, only then you have to initiate server call. For more reference please refer UI-Grid API help doc.